# Casadi IVP integrator RHSFUNC FAIL

Tags: ode

I've been using CasADI to solve an IVP, but for some combinations of parameters the solver doesn't terminate. Sending a keyboard interrupt returns the error message in the title ("CV_RHSFUNC_FAIL"). Adjusting the maximum number of steps that the solver is allowed to take results in the function returning a different error (CV_TOO_MUCH_WORK) for all parameter combinations.  I can obtain the solution to the IVP for these parameter sets using the SciPy odeint function.

Ideally I would like a solution like this

```
try:
   CasadiSolver()
except:
   ScipySolver()
```

However, because the Casadi solver runs forever instead of returning an error I cannot implement this solution. Has anyone seen this error before and knows what it means? If so, could they tell me how to stop the CasADI IVP solver running forever, and cause it to return an error instead?

Comment: CasADi uses the SunDials solvers for ODE problems. Which solver did you use? Can you reproduce the problem with a simplified ODE system that you can present here? It looks like the step size controller ran the step size down to near zero, which indicates that the system at that point is non-smooth or otherwise stiff. Does your ODE function have jumps, kinks or other non-analytical components?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the quick reply - I am using the casadi integrator class, which uses CVodes in SunDials. I have not tried to reproduce the problem, but will attempt to do so now. The system I am trying to solver does have a discontinuity in it. Is there a way to set the minimum step size in casadi?

Comment: You could also use events to integrate up to the discontinuity and after that with smooth systems, so that the step size controller does not come into a singular situation.